# Class型と文字列から対応するenum値を取得するには？

Tags: java

```
public enum MyEnum {
    HOGE,
    FUGA;
}
```

下記のClass<?>とStringからMyEnum.HOGEを取得するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
またClass<?>型(cl)からenum値すべて列挙可能でしょうか？

```
class<?> cl = MyEnum.class;
String value = "HOGE";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Class#getEnumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--)で列挙型の定数一覧を取得できます。

```
Class<?> cl = MyEnum.class;
String value = "HOGE";

for (Object o: cl.getEnumConstants()) {
  if (o.toString().equals(value)) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s:%s", o.getClass(), o));
    // class MyEnum:HOGE
    System.out.println(o.equals(MyEnum.HOGE));
    // true
  }
}
```

Comment: おかげ様で列挙できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4):

[`Enum#valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) が、そのものではないでしょうか。

```
Enum<?> v = Enum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, "HOGE");
System.out.println(v == MyEnum.HOGE); // true
System.out.println(v == MyEnum.FUGA); // false
```

列挙は [`Class#getEnumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--) でできそうです。

Comment: ああ `T` じゃなくて `?` から調べたい、ってことですかね?

Comment: 分かり難くてすみません。リフレクションをやっていて、enumの復元に喘いでいました。
yohjpさんの回答で、列挙と値の取得が出来ました。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 2):

列挙してみました。

```
Class<?> cl = MyEnum.class;

Field[] fields = cl.getFields();
for (Field f: fields) {
    String name = f.getName();
    Enum e = (Enum) f.get(null);
    System.out.printf("%s=%d\n", name, e.ordinal());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

試していないのでうまくいかないかもですが、classオブジェクトを使って`name()`をリフレクションで呼ぶという方法はどうでしょうか？